# Override Visual Studio's Treatment of Component-Derived Class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, system.componentmodel

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio that I want to treat my class as a regular class and not a component? My class is declared like this:

```
public class WebDavClient : WebClient
{
}
```

I guess that, because `WebClient` derives from `System.ComponentModel.Component`, Visual Studio assumes it is a component. So double clicking the file in Solution Explorer brings up a designer surface instead of the code. Moreover, if I add another class before the declaration above, double clicking the file in Solution Explorer gives me a "The class WebDavClient can be designed, but is not the first class in the file" error.

In all cases, I only want to treat this class as a regular class and will never want a designer surface. Is there any way to override Visual Studio's default behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this attribute:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]
public class WebDavClient : WebClient
{
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designercategoryattribute.aspx